# How to check if date is in correct format i.e. yyyy-mmm-dd?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I'm receiving data from a service call and want to make sure that the string is in correct date format like:

```
2015-Nov-19
```

I have tried to use parse function with the format `yyyy-mmm-dd`, but it is also allowing dates like `2015-11-19`. What do I do?

Comment: hmm. using regex works too. though im not sure about this pattern. `\d{4}-\w{3}-\d{2}`, then just parse it see if its valid.

Comment: Can you show the code where "the format yyyy-mmm-dd also allows dates like 2015-11-19"?

Comment: @GazWinter that's actually bad advise `DataTime.TryParseExact` would be a better option

Comment: @MethodMan quite right and I have now removed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DateTime.TryParseExact

```
DateTime dt;
string[] formats = { "yyyy-MMM-dd"};
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, formats, 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //your condition fail code goes here
    return false;
}
else
{
    //success code
}
```

Comment: `yay` -> party like it's 1999

Comment: Fixed typo, I blame my phone ☺

Comment: @TahreemIqbal Why you select this as an answer o.O? You said _but it is also allowing dates like_ `2015-11-19` but this answer does not handle that.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood his question, I believe he doesn't want that format to be supported.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use [`MMM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MMM_Specifier) instead of `mmm` with a *english-based* culture like `InvariantCulture`. There is no `mmm` as a custom date and time specifier.

And if you wanna parse multiple formats, [`DateTime.TryParseExact` has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes `string[]` as a paramter so you can supply multiple formats.

```
string s = "2015-Nov-19"; // or 2015-11-19
DateTime dt;
string[] formats = {"yyyy-MMM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd"};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Successfully parse
}
```

I used `MM` specifier in second format but if your single digit months does not have leading zero, you need to use `M` specifier instead.

Comment: You were better the first time. @TimSchmelter notes that the OP sasid it accepted dates like `2015-11-19`, but that was a **problem** with the original, since there is no `mmm` the parse treats it as an opaque literal with no bearing on the date produced, and so parses `2015-11-19` as meaning `2015-01-19` (there's no value obtained for month, so it defaults to `1`).

Comment: @JonHanna Exactly. Even if `mmm` were a _valid_ specifier, since it points minutes, month value would be `1` by default as you said. Why you said _I'm better the first time_ by the way? My first revision does not  contains parsing the `2015-01-19` case :)

Comment: Exactly. Your revision contains the parsing for the `2015-11-19` case, which it should be blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify the expected format string appropriately.

Comment: I want the date to be like this: 2015-Nov-19

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression. For dates, it can be hairy if you want to account for the number of days any month is allowed and for leap-years. Perhaps a two-step approach would be easier.

1. Check that the format is correct with Regular Expressions.
2. Check that the data is correct by casting it to a date and catching any exceptions.

Comment: Actually - I like @Jon 's answer much better. I didn't know about the "Exact" variant. This is one of the reasons I have a sincere appreciation for StackOverflow - I learn something new even when trying to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Another very simple way of converting a date to your preferred format:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:SS"));
```

You can put whatever format you want in the string. And the object to be converted into string must be a DateTime object. You can later reconvert the string into DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Use  this piece of code :

```
        string stringdate = "2015-Nov-19";

        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(stringdate);

        string tempdate = date.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd");

        if (tempdate == stringdate)
        {
            // Successfully parsed string goes here 
        }
```

It checks from the string whether the date is in particular format or not, if it is in particular format it is successfully parsed else not.
And it will not parse dates like 2015-11-19, which you wanted.